# Get Json Data From php page in swift 3

Tags: php, json, swift3

I am having trouble getting a simple Json object from my php page into my ios app. I am using Swift 3 in xcode 8. I have tried multiple tutorials with no avail. I keep getting the error "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." I have checked my php page with a Json validator and it seems to be fine. Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Here is my Json data that is echoed to my php page.

{"SSID":"TESTSSID","PASS":"TESTPASS"}

As you can see, all I am trying to do is be able to get SSID and PASS into a variable in Swift so that I can output the data to the app. Here is what I have so far for the swift code. (sorry if it is terrible, I am a newbie and just hacked it together)

This is in my ViewDidLoad()..

```
    let urlString = "http://192.168.51.1/mytestPHP.php"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {

                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                let SSID = parsedData["SSID"] as! [String:Any]

                print(SSID)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
      }

}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON response both `SSID` and `PASS` keys having `String` as value not `Dictionary`.

```
do {
    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    if let ssid = parsedData["SSID"] as? String,
       let pass = parsedData["PASS"] as? String {
         print(ssid, pass)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

**Note:** As error suggesting your response is not valid so try once converting data to `string` and check what you are getting in response. Add below line before calling `JSONSerialization` and the response of it here.

```
print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! I replaced your do/catch block and got the same error. Then added the print statement before the JSONSerialization and got this...

Comment: @JonBell get what ?

Comment: Optional("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.ww3.oo\nrg/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n   <head>\n     <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n     <title>APP INTERFACE</title>\n   </head>\n<body>\n\n{\"SSID\":\"TESTSSID\",\"PASS\":\"TESTPASS\"}</body>\n</html>\n")
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start...

Comment: @JonBell So you are getting this HTML in your response not the JSON `"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"ww3.oo\nrg/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n <head>\n <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n <title>APP INTERFACE</title>\n </head>\n<body>\n\n{\"SSID\":\"TESTSSID\",\"PASS\":\"TESTPAS‌​S\"}</body>\n</html>‌​\n"` Check properly in your PHP script or you are missing something

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. I did not remove my HTML tags prior to creating the PHP script. All is well. Thank you so much for the debugging help!

Comment: @JonBell Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically getting an invalid JSON error, so either your PHP script is not returning the JSON you think it's returning or it's not returning anything at all.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the case but this is exactly what is printed to the screen from the PHP script..  {"SSID":"TESTSSID","PASS":"TESTPASS"}

Comment: it looks like you are not printing json but just plain string are you using this echo json_encode($data); ? you should add your PHP code to the question because that's where the problem is.